# Google sheet Auto-incrementing ID/Primarykey

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In this google sheet function, a primary key is automatically added to the first column on change. The problem with this function is the fact that when a new row is added the row below also gets a primary key despite the other cells in the row is blank.

**How can this function be modified, so that the primary key only will be added if i.e. the first cell to the right (cell B) is not empty?**

```
function myFunction() {

  var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0;
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows+1, 2);

  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {
    try {
      var id = vals[row][AUTOINC_COLUMN];
      Logger.log(id);Logger.log((""+id).length ===0);
      if ((""+id).length === 0) {
        // Here the columns & rows are 1-indexed
        worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue(row);
      }
    } catch(ex) {
      // Keep calm and carry on
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You have not provided enough information. _a primary key is automatically added to the first column on change_ What does this mean? You also don't say whether your data is numeric or text. It would be helpful to have a copy of your spreadsheet. However, as a stab in the dark, try this: add a variable after id:`var col2 = vals[row][1];`, then use this new line to evaluate them `if(id.length !=0 && col2.length!=0){`. So if id is NOT empty AND col2 is NOT empty, then you can add the key. if either value is a string, then simple change to `id.toString().length`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use a script for this, just enter this in A2  and then copy all the way down. put a 0 (or 100, wherever you want it to start) in cell A1.

```
=if(B2="","",A1+1)
```

Comment: Simple and Perfect. Thanks

Comment: If a previous row has been deleted, this would generate a reference error

Comment: This also wouldn't work if you need to be able to sort the data. Each different sort order would have different primary keys.

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I would add my answer. I would not use a formula because that would recalculate if you ever sort the sheet (not good if you are referencing primary keys elsewhere). The other code-based solution assumes that records will only be added at the end of the sheet and the last row is the highest primary key (i.e. will end up with duplicate keys if you ever resort the sheet).

This code will work no matter where you insert a record, or how you sort the data.
It does assume that you will never remove the row with the highest primary key (removing a row with less than the highest primary key won't be a problem).

```
function auto_increment_column() {
  const AUTO_INCREMENT_SHEET = "Sheet1";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(AUTO_INCREMENT_SHEET);

  var nextIncrementValue = Math.max.apply(Math, sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues().flat().filter(e => !isNaN(parseFloat(e))))

  var rows = sheet.getRange("A:B");

  for(var i = 1; i <= rows.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var cellA = rows.getCell(i, 1);
    var cellB = rows.getCell(i, 2);

    if(cellA.getValue() === "" && cellB.getValue() !== "") {
      cellA.setValue(nextIncrementValue++);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't understand how to make this function available in my Sheet. I created an Apps Script project and added the code...but Google's documentation has left me mystified from there. Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: There are a few ways to do it. You can set up an installable **on edit** trigger from your project to run that function anytime the spreadsheet is edited, use the **onEdit** simple trigger (this one can be finicky sometimes since it requires the editing user to authorize the script), set up a menu item using an **on load** trigger (you will have to run the function from a menu. It won't be automatic as the sheet is edited), or, finally, you can run the code from the project screen (this is definitely the least convenient).

Answer (score 2):

The formula
`=ARRAYFORMULA(sequence(match(2,1/(B:B<>""),1),1,0,1))`
entered into cell A1 will auto increment Column A to last cell in column B containing some value.

I use this in cell A1 on Form Responses Page because it is automatic. No chance that a new row will exceed my auto increment count because I didn't drag a formula down far enough.

Above formula controls Rows ,Columns, Start Value, & Step Value. More info: [infoinspired.com](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sequence-function-in-google-sheets/)

Note: Using a formula such as
`=if(C2="","","value if false")` to insert cell value in column B will always be counted.
Both `" "` and `"value if false"` evaluate to a cell with something in it.
Use of " " to say blank or empty is not TRUE.
Try instead `=if(C2="",,"value if false")` to avoid unexpected results in functions and formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be what you are looking for:

```
function auto_increment_col() {
  var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 1;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var last_row        = worksheet.getLastRow();
  var last_inc_val = worksheet.getRange(last_row, AUTOINC_COLUMN).getValue();

  //if auto_inc column is blank and the column next to auto_inc column is not blank, then assume its a new row
  var is_new_row = last_inc_val == "" && worksheet.getRange(last_row, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).getValue() != "";
  Logger.log("new_row:" + is_new_row + ", last_inc_val:" + last_inc_val );
  if (is_new_row) {
    var prev_inc_val = worksheet.getRange(last_row-1, AUTOINC_COLUMN).getValue();
    worksheet.getRange(last_row, AUTOINC_COLUMN).setValue(prev_inc_val+1);
  }
}
```